# Get the results after the it is closed

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I am using the sqlite driver with java. As you know the typical order is

```
Create Statement
Execute Statement
Get ResultSet

Process Results

close ResultSet
close statement
```

The problem is that all of above is in one method and  I want the caller to get the results and process it. However since the results are returned at the end of the method then by then the statement and the result set is closed.

The only work around I can think of is to have the RS and the Stmnt be a class variable and have the caller close them but this will pose problem if it is multi threaded env.

What is the recommended way to achieve what  I want?
Thanks

```
public ResultSet runQuery(String sql) {

        try {

            st = conn.createStatement();
            rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

            rs.close();
            st.close()

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DatabaseHelper.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        return rs
    }
```

From another file

```
private void displayListOfEmployee(){
         String sql = "Select * from employee";
         ResultSet rs = DB.getInstance().runQuery(sql);
         while(rs.next()!=null){
             System.out.println(.....); // display value of column
         }
}
```

Comment: You should ask yourself if you really want to wrap JDBC like this, because it goes against how JDBC should be used (+ you seem to be using fields for `conn`, `st` and `rs` which is an accident waiting to happen under concurrent use).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `Consumer<ResultSet>` parameter to the method:

```
public void query(String query, Consumer<ResultSet> consumer) {
     // Create Statement
     try (Statement stmt = ...) {
          // Execute Statement
          ResultSet rs = ...
          consumer.accept(rs);
     }
}
```

With this the caller can extract its data from the result set and you can guarantee that resources are closed.

A variation would be to use a `Function` parameter and compute a return value:

```
public <T> T query(String query, Function<ResultSet,T> function) {
     // Create Statement
     try (Statement stmt = ...) {
          // Execute Statement
          ResultSet rs = ...
          return function.apply(rs);
     }
}
```

Since `Consumer.accept` and `Function.apply` do not allow to throw checked exceptions you may want to define similar functional interfaces which allow checked exceptions and use it in that method.

UPDATE:

Your example would translate to:

```
private void displayListOfEmployee(){
     String sql = "Select * from employee";
     DB.getInstance().runQuery(sql, rs -> {
         while (rs.next())
             System.out.println(.....); // display value of column
     });
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the Consumer<ResultSet> method? I am not sure what you mean. I am sorry if my question is dumb

Comment: @Snake add a short example to your question how you intended to use your function and I translate that into the consumer version

Comment: Elegant and no additional resource required.

Comment: Interesting.. I never knew that this concept exists.. Well learn every day.. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution would be to use a [`CachedRowSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sql/rowset/CachedRowSet.html), which is populated from a `ResultSet` but can outlive the associated `Statement/Connection` the `ResultSet` was produced by.

Note this will read the entire `ResultSet` into memory.